# Retrieve failed entities from ExecuteMultipleResponse method

Tags: c#, dynamics-crm-online

I am using the Execute Multiple Response class to pass in an Entity Collection for Upsert into Dynamics CRM, I would like to know how to add the failed entity names to a collection and then use exception handling on each of these entities.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming you create your `ExecuteMultipleRequest` something like this:

```
var entityCollection; // your EntityCollection
var requests = new ExecuteMultipleRequest();

foreach (var entity in entityCollection.Entities) {
    var upsertRequest = new UpsertRequest { Target = entity };
    requests.Requests.Add(upsertRequest);
}
```

You should be able to execute the request, iterate through the `responses` and for each determine whether a fault occurred:

```
var responses = service.Execute(requests);
var errors = new List<Entity>();

foreach (var response in responses.Responses) {
    if (response.Fault != null) {
        var entity = entityCollection[response.RequestIndex];
        errors.Add(entity);
    }
}
```

`response.RequestIndex` is used to access the response's corresponding request by matching their indexes.

`responses.Responses` contains a collection of `ExecuteMultipleResponseItem`. Documentation on their properties can be found [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/microsoft.xrm.sdk.executemultipleresponseitem.aspx).

Comment: Thanks for the response Dave, helps a lot!! A couple of follow up questions. requests[response.RequestIndex] is the index of the ExecuteMultipleRequest , how would you get the entity from the index? My errors.Add(entity) gives me "cannot convert from 'object' to 'Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.Entity'

Comment: My mistake, you should get your entity from the `EntityCollection`, not from the `ExecuteMultipleRequest.Requests`. Therefore the line would read: `var entity = entityCollection[response.RequestIndex];`